# How to assign a handsontable grid to the window object and how to use it

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to use the window to access my handsontable grid and change some things with the associated functions in an ajax callback function. I'm trying to use the `window.variable` (with the advice of ZekeDroid) to use a handsontable instance in an ajax callback function. When I run my code, firebug tells me that the variable is undefined.

So I declared my handsontable like that :

```
window.hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data_traitement,
  stretchH: 'all',
  minSpareRows: 1,
  observeChanges : true,
  rowHeaders: false,
```

And I'm trying to use it like that :

```
window.hotTraitemenT.setDataAtCell(1,0,'bonjour');
```

I don't know how to use the window instances, it's the first time but if there is an other solution, I take it too !

Comment: by the way, this is just a very generic case of context issues. I would highly recommend you read a javascript tutorial to better understand context in this language. It's not hard but can be a little confusing at times.

Comment: @ZekeDroid I looked some tutorials and I asked on different plateforms. So sometimes, it tells me to remove the `var`, sometimes I need to code in the `$(document).ready(function()`. I tried with window.variable.  But there is no way, it doesn't work ^^'